# What does the lex means?

Tags: php, lex

```
<!*> := yyleng = YYCURSOR - SCNG(yy_text);


<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"exit" {
    return T_EXIT;
}

<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"die" {
    return T_EXIT;
}
```

I've never seen such lex syntax,but found it in PHP's source package.

The lex syntax that I'm familiar with is:

```
dollar {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>` defines a [start condition](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) for the rule matched.